# Self referencing association in Phoenix using Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I've just started fiddeling around with Phoenix, and Elixir. So I have reached the point were I am trying to get a working rest-api endpoint to work with a prerequisite JSON.

So I have this module:

```
defmodule MyApp.Housing.Part do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @primary_key {:id, :integer, []}
  schema "parts" do
    field :level, :integer
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :parent, MyApp.Housing.Part
    has_many :children, MyApp.Housing.Part, foreign_key: :parent_id
    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(part, params \\ %{}) do
    part
    |> cast(params, [:title, :level, :id, :parent_id])
    |> put_assoc(:children, required: false)
    |> put_assoc(:parent, required: false)
    |> validate_required([:title, :level, :id])
  end
end
```

And the module in which the table is created

```
 defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateParts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:parts, primary_key: false) do
      add :id, :integer, primary_key: true
      add :title, :string
      add :level, :integer
      add :parent_id, references(:parts)
      add :children, references(:parts)
      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:parts, [:children])
    create index(:parts, [:parent_id])
  end
end
```

The inteded functionallity is for a part to be able to have multiple children but only one parent. And these are defined in a JSON like this:

```
{"id": 10,
    "title": "Matt",
    "level": 0,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": null}
```

So my problem is the following:

- "changeset" requires that the incoming object looks like `{"part":{}}`otherwise the ActionClauseError gets thrown.
- When defining the object as above I get the error `children":["is invalid"]`. And I can't figure out how to get a valid one, if I did I probably could figure out the problem.

I might take the wrong approach here but would gladly accept any help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @steve-pallen, it's not necessary to store any references to `children` in the database. Determining whether or not a `Part` is a parent or child, as well as which `Part`s are its children or which `Part` is its parent can be determined fully by the `parent_id` field.

You described in your question that each `Part` "can only have one parent, but multiple children". It's not explicit in your question how many levels the relationship allows: i.e. can a `Part` be both a parent and a child? In which case, there would be potentially infinite levels of nesting:

```
part1
  |- part2
    |- part3
      |- part4
```

In this case, `part1` is the parent of `part2`, `part2` is itself the parent of `part3`, etc. I'm going to assume for my answer that there is no limit to the amount of nesting.

Given this case, your schema definition is 100% correct:

```
belongs_to :parent, MyApp.Housing.Part
has_many :children, MyApp.Housing.Part, foreign_key: :parent_id
```

I think the primary issue is with your changeset function. Remember that with `put_assoc/3`, it's expected that all the models referenced by `parent` and `children` already exist in the DB (see the docs for [cast_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.11/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3-alternatives-to-cast_assoc-3)). For simplicity I suggest that you don't use `put_assoc` **or** `cast_assoc` and instead manage each model in isolation. If you change your changeset function to this (I've removed `id` since it's not necessary):

```
def changeset(part, params \\ %{}) do
  part
  |> cast(params, [:title, :level, :parent_id])
  |> validate_required([:title, :level])
end
```

Then you can build the nested relationship I showed above by doing 4 inserts in isolation (much easier to reason about, and probably more in line with how you'd handle DB updates from a form or script):

```
part1 = 
  MyApp.Housing.Part.changeset(%MyApp.Housing.Part{}, %{title: "part1", level: 0, parent_id: nil})
  |> Repo.insert!()

part2 = 
  MyApp.Housing.Part.changeset(%MyApp.Housing.Part{}, %{title: "part2", level: 0, parent_id: part1.id})
  |> Repo.insert!()

part3 = 
  MyApp.Housing.Part.changeset(%MyApp.Housing.Part{}, %{title: "part3", level: 0, parent_id: part2.id})
  |> Repo.insert!()  

part4 = 
  MyApp.Housing.Part.changeset(%MyApp.Housing.Part{}, %{title: "part4", level: 0, parent_id: part3.id})
  |> Repo.insert!()
```

Assuming we want to get `part2`, we can load it along with its parent and children like this:

```
part2 = Repo.preload(part2, [:parent, :children])
# part2.parent == %MyApp.Housing.Part{title: "part1", ...}
# part2.children == [%MyApp.Housing.Part{title: "part3", ...}]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will almost certainly help. I will take a look asap.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to fix is the migration. You don't want the children field since that is a has_many relationship and is handled by the parent_id field in the children. It should look like this:

```
 defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateParts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:parts, primary_key: false) do
      add :id, :integer, primary_key: true
      add :title, :string
      add :level, :integer
      add :parent_id, references(:parts)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:parts, [:parent_id])
  end
end
```

Handling the children in the changeset depends on a couple things.

- What does the incoming payload look like when there are children?
- Will there be new children in the children list or just existing children?